# Smarty, count length of array key string?

Tags: php, count, smarty

`{$smarty.post.email}` outputs "john@yahoo.com"

`{$smarty.post.email|count}` outputs "1" instead of "14" - string length.

`{$smarty.post.email[0]|count}` outputs "1" as well.

How can i find length of key named "email"?

Comment: Wouldn't just `{$smarty.post.email|strlen}` work?

Comment: I forgot to mention its smarty v2 and it does work! i forgot to check that i remember looking for way to count string length for long time and never try |strlen solution. thanks

Comment: Perfect! Then it would be cool if you could close the question by selecting an answer. You can answer your own question or I can add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
{$smarty.post.email|count_characters:true}
```

source : http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.count.characters.tpl

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = strlen($smarty.post.email);

$count = strlen($smarty[post][email]);
```

> **strlen** returns the length of a string. Key names are strings.
>
> **count** returns the number of keys in an array.

Comment: i have smarty v2 |@count returns number of keys in arrat |count returns number of caracters in single var non array i assume.

What supposed to be strlent() php function? i prefer not to use php code in smarty templates.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what 'smarty' is.  I thought that you meant 'smartly'.  If you're using php, I don't see what the flaw in using strlen would be, but I could be mistaken.  Have you tried it to see if it works at least?